# How do i set .equals equal to the result of startActivityForResult

Tags: android

im kinda new to programming and would like to make some sort of like a login and register page. so from my login page i click register and it would go to the register page and i want the username/password i get from the register page to be used in the previous login page to login into the app. But i cant seem to set the username/password using the result. Only able to set the textview. pls help heres the code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText Name;
private EditText Password;
private TextView Info;
private Button Login;
private int counter = 5;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etName);
    Password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPass);
    Info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvInfo);
    Login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

    Info.setText("No Of Attempts Remaining: 5");


    Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            validate(Name.getText().toString(),Password.getText().toString());
        }
    });
}

private void validate(String userName, String userPassword){
    if(userName.equals("") && userPassword.equals("")){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    else{
        counter--;

        Info.setText("No Of Attempts Remaining: " + String.valueOf(counter));
        if(counter == 0){
            Login.setEnabled(false);
        }

    }
}

public void facebooklogin(View myview){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MenuActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
public void register(View myview) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, RegisterActivity    .class);
    startActivityForResult(i, 1);
}
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String reginame = data.getStringExtra("NAME");
            String regipass = data.getStringExtra("PASS");
            Name.setText("" + reginame);
            Password.setText("" + regipass);

        }
    }
}
```

How do i set the

```
private void validate(String userName, String userPassword){
   if(userName.equals("") && userPassword.equals("")){
      Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
      startActivity(intent);
 }
```

to be equal to the onActivityResult reginame and regipass

Answer (score 1):

your condition is wrong it should be like this:-

```
  private void validate(String userName, String userPassword){
  if(!userName.equals("") && !userPassword.equals("")){
  Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
  startActivity(intent);
  }
```

Comment: but that doesn't do anything besides starting the activity with any username and pass. What i want is to have the username/password i got from the registeractivity to be the username and password for the login

Comment: have you tried printing log inside OnActivityResult that you'r getting data like printing name in log

Answer (score 0):

First Activity. 
Send information

```
Intent send = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
        send.putExtra("login",editText.getText());
        send.putExtra("password",editText1.getText());
        startActivity(send);
```

Second Activity.
Get Information

```
if(getIntent()!=null){
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        editText.setText(intent.getStringExtra("login")) ;
         editText1.setText(intent.getStringExtra("password")) ;
    }
```